# Adding live rating and review in Windows 8 javascript application

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have developed a windows 8 application and wanted to add rate and review functionality in my application as when user go to setting from charm bar he/she should see rate and riview and then that page allow user to rate app at store. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Rate and Review" entry on the Settings flyout is automatically added when your app gets listed in the store.  You don't have to take any action here.

If you're asking about exposing that same functionality elsewhere in your app, you can [link to your app in the store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh974767.aspx) via protocol activation, but not directly to the rate/review page.